# chrome object element on top of everything issue

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome

hi and thanks for stopping by.
i tried and digged the web but this is something i really cant get to work.

so i grab this object from another website via its feed (so i cant edit the source material)

```
<object width="100%" height="420" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/8UFhdYhE9ko?version=3&amp;hl=de_DE" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <embed width="100%" height="420" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/8UFhdYhE9ko?version=3&amp;hl=de_DE" allowFullScreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" />
</object>
```

now, in chrome this object is above every other object no matter the z-index. that is due to the fact that there is no wmode definded. i know that and i know that i could modify the source via jquery and put this wmode inside, with someting like

```
$("object").each(function() {
    $(this).children("embed").attr("wmode", "opaque");
});
```

​
but nothing changes at all in good old chome. my iframes work fine, i did almost the same thing, all good. but on the object, i cant get it to work. could it be, that the jquery move is too late..? in my js fiddle below i have to videos, one has the wmode attribute insinde the embed tag, and this one works fine, so i know thats the correct attribute and the correct place to put it. but the other one, that should get the attribute via jquery, doesnt change at all.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/WTE7X/). its a red box above the objects. in "normal" browsers the box is above both objects, in chrome the upper movie is above the red box.

Comment: It works fine in my chrome version, even without the jQuery. What version are you using and on what OS?

Comment: wtf. chrome 18.0.1025.168 on mac osx 10.7.3

Comment: I was using version 21.0.1135.0, when trying on 18.0.1025.168 it didn't work either. How are you grapping the object? Could you add the wmode parameter directly to the html before rendering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function to copy all the objects, insert the wmode parameter and replace the old objects with the new ones:

```
$("object").each(function() {
    var $newObject = $(this).clone(true);
    $newObject.children("embed").attr("wmode", "opaque");
    $(this).replaceWith($newObject);
});
```

​
​Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WTE7X/3/

If you're using PHP, you can do this fairly simple, if `$html` is a string containing the objects:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('html');
$finalDoc = new DOMDocument();
$objects = $doc->getElementsByTagName('object');
for($i = 0; $i < $objects->length; $i++)
{
    $embeds = $objects->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('embed');
    for($j = 0; $j < $embeds->length; $j++)
    {
        $embeds->item($j)->setAttribute('wmode', 'opaque');
    }
    $finalDoc->appendChild($finalDoc->importNode($objects->item($i), true));
}

$fixedHTML = $finalDoc->saveHTML(); // This holds the new HMTL to output
```

Comment: ..just when i finished coding my workaround in php ;)
but thank you very much. ill use your solution cause i still dont trust my regex skills.
so in the end it looks like you cant edit rendered objects. thanks